# Is it possible to speed up this Ajax JSON call for use with datatables?

Tags: jquery, ajax, performance, datatables, coldfusion

My website is https://usedlens.co.uk/

Google Dev Tools - XHR header details you can see it makes a call to
https://usedlens.co.uk/data.cfc?method=getData

- On production it takes ~12 seconds to load 3.6MB
- On development it takes <1 second to load 22.9MB

Development and production have roughly the same amount of data and the code is the same.

I've experimented with using server side processing, and it loads the data quicker 3-4 seconds, but pagination/search/sorting all have the same 3-4 second response time. So I have stuck with the ajax option.

My datatables initialisation

```
var resultsTable = $('#resultsTable').DataTable(
    {
        'serverSide': false,
        'deferRender': true,
         'ajax': {
            'url': 'data.cfc?method=getData'
         },
         'columns': [            
            { 'data': 'productname' },
            { 'data': 'price' },
            { 'data': 'retailersite' }
         ],
        'columnDefs': [
           { "targets": [1,2], "searchable": false },
           { "width":"10%","targets": [1]},
           { "width":"20%","targets": [2]}
         ]
    }
);
```

I replaced my CFC source with a JSON text file, it still takes 8-11 seconds.

Is there anything more I can do to speed this up?

Comment: Odds are, the latency is all on the database side. CF can only do so much when the DB is taking time to return the data. Since the size of the data is relatively the same in both environments, how well indexed are those tables? When's the last time they were re-indexed? Pagination should be the better approach, but it depends on the query and how well the indexes perform. Which database are you using?

Comment: I'm using mysql, I've only just added an id as a primary key to the product table - The table gets cleared once a day and I hadn't added an id before now since the auto increment id would be ridiculous before long.

Comment: The host tried it from their end, and it took 4 seconds. Maybe I should have paid more for a UK host!

Comment: I turned the data into a text file containing the JSON, it is taking 8-11 seconds on production, 144ms on dev. So at least I can rule out any latency issues with the database or cfc code even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched to server-side processing

https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/

So that I only passed through the current records in view (10/25/50/100) instead of all 50,000.

It wasn't the first time I tried it, but this time I fixed errors in my code causing it to run slow.

Properly implemented it works well.

Comment: You should write up a summary on what you did so that the next person can benefit.

Comment: Expanded upon the solution and put a link to datatables implementation guide.